# what is int, fundamental data type

Tags: c++, int, typedef

Can anyone tell sth about what is int data type in C++, drilling the headers I can find

```
typedef int                 INT;
```

What/where is the linkage between type in text code and physical storage in RAM? Compiler must know what is this int. And I ask - where it is explained to compiler?

Comment: the `typedef` creates a sort of alias for that type. So now anywhere in your source code where you could put `int` you can use `INT`.

Comment: Who is "sth" and why can't he ask the question himself?

Comment: It sounds like you're not even slightly familiar with C++ if you're asking where `int` is defined... Perhaps you should also ask where `typedef` and `;` are defined.

Comment: @Robᵩ By "sth", I believe OP meant "something".

Comment: it is obvious, I ask what is int not INT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `int` is an integer. At the most rudimentary level, it is simply a set of bytes intepreted as a numeric value. Modern processors (and operating systems) support multiple sizes of integer, though 32-bit and 64-bit (4 and 8 bytes respectively) are most common.

In terms of representation in hardware, they're simply data lines set to high and low voltages. A 32-bit parallel data bus will have 32 data lines, each representing one bit. If you want to represent the number 100, you convert it to a binary representation (i.e. `1100100`) and therefore set lines 3, 6 and 7 high, and the rest low. The processor and other microcontrollers can interpret this signal based on their internal functionality and programming.

Comment: so the compiler has to contain information what is int? that it is 4 bytes i.e.?

Comment: The `int` type is kinda complicated in that it changes size based on certain OS details. You can use `int32_t` if you want a fixed-size 32-bit integer. There are also issues related to endianness (bit ordering), which you can read about on Wikipedia. You should also look around for other int-size questions on here to get a good overview of the complexities.

Answer (score 4):

`typedef int INT` doesn't define `int`. It's just the opposite: It defines `INT` to be like `int`. `int` itself is defined in the guts of the compiler, not in source files.

A typedef doesn't map to memory at all. It is simply text describing type of storage, size, etc.. It's the variable of that type that is mapped to memory.

Comment: yes, it is obvious, looks like first guys were too hasty and didn't want to read my question closely enough

Comment: ok, so where on my computer with VS2010 can I find this information about how compiler treats fundamental type int?

Comment: I think nowhere becouse it is just that if in the text file compiler find int he knows that this is 4 bytes (but where it is exactly stated????) and based on this fact all the rest of code is understand (??)

Comment: Correct. int is not defined in text but in the compiler applicatio (cl.exe on visual studio 6, or one of the DLLs it uses). The only thing you can explore about it is ``sizeof(int)``

Answer (score 2):

`int` is described in the c++ standard §3.9.1 Fundamental Types. The actual size is implementation dependent. Concerning the sizes of the fundamental types, C++ references C99. See the `<climits>` header, where values such as `MIN_INT` and `MAX_INT` are defined, and the functionality available in the `<limits>` header, particularly `std::numeric_limits`. This provides functionality to determine ranges of different types on your platform, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) for more details.

The typedef you mention simply means that you can use the symbol `INT` to mean `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot go any deeper because `int` is primitive C/C++ type.

> what/where is the linkage between type in text code and physical
>   storage in RAM? it cannot be end, becouse what the compiler is
>   supposed to do when you tell him int i= . he must know what is this
>   int.

For Windows case (I do not have experience with other Operating System), compiler builds your code into executable file which there are two main sectors: data sector and code sector. Lets say that you declare `int i`, when your code got compiled, it will translate into a memory location (e.g: 0x0000004). When Operating System loads your executable file (which in Windows is .exe or .dll), OS will create a virtual memory for your application. (e.g 0x100000000). So your `int i` will be located at 0x100000004 in your physical memory, but located at 0x0000004 in your application virtual memory.

The above explanation is simplified version of how thing works (Actual thing can be more complicated)

Comment: and compiler knows that there are 4 bytes required? so this information that for int 4 bytes is contained in the compiler's code?

Comment: You should know that it is human-being that creates Compiler, and it is up to the Compiler's creator to decide number of bytes that `int` needs. However, there are good reasons (related to performance) why everyone choose 4 bytes (for 32-bits processor) or 8 bytes (64-bits processor).

Answer (score 1):

C++ is not purely object-oriented, although every defined variable is called "object" in C++ terminology. There are types which are not instances of a class and `int` is one of them.

An `int` is just a set of at least 16 consecutive bits which are interpreted as a signed integer. The actual size and how a certain bit pattern is mapped to an integer number is mainly compiler and platform dependent.